# Can I write a excel cell reference based on a fixed column and variable row?

Tags: excel

I already know the column is **P**, but the row number is based on **count(I$2:I6)+1**

Can I write anything to reference this cell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Index() for that. Ignore anyone who points you toward INDIRECT(). Avoid INDIRECT(). It is volatile.

```
=Index(P:P,count(I$2:I6)+1)
```